# Show More/Less option in datatable column <td> if text is longer then 20 character

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatable

I have datatable with couple of row, such as Description,ShortDescription,User,Type etc....
Once user create a long in `column` Description the row is very ugly and content is unreadable.
So my idea is when text is more then 20 character long put `...` which will be `<a>` anchort tag and it will display text, something like `page-break`. I try to find some usefull post here but unfortunettly I couldn't

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566137/show-more-show-less-with-jquery)

So far here is DEMO of my table

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6qyfxed5/12/)

Here is picture

[image]

So something like add in `<td>` option when text is longer then 20 character option `Show More / Show Less`
Any help ? Any guide ?

And here is my source code:

```
   var dataTable;



$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});


   function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Manager/Ticket/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "description",
                "width": "15%",
                "render": function () {
                    return '<a href="#" class="showmore" data-content="toggle-text">Vise</a>'
                }
            },
            { "data": "shortDescription", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "ticketType.name", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "status", "width": "10%" },
            {
                "data": "applicationUser.name",
                "width": "10%",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a id="' + data + '" class="text-info user-details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userDetails" href="' + data + '" target_blank>' + data + '</a>'
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `
                            <div class="text-center">   
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Details/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                   <i class="fas fa-info-circle">Detalji/Chat</i>
                                </a>   
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Upsert/${data}" class="btn btn-primary text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit">Uredi</i>
                                </a>                           
                            </div>
                           `;
                }, "width": "15%"
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

JS function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".td").hide();
    $(".showmore").on("click", function () {
        var txt = $(".table-info").is(':visible') ? 'Vise' : 'Manje';
        $(".showmore").text(txt);
        $(this).next('.table-info').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Here is table

```
<div class="p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Kratak Opis</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme slanja</th>
                <th>Vrsta Tiketa</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Korisnik</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show more show less in a jquery data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542680/show-more-show-less-in-a-jquery-data-table)

Comment: No, doesn't work for me ! 
I update my question

Comment: @andrewjames Unfortunetlly I didnt get anything in console

Comment: @andrewjames I update my question. Please check

Comment: OK - thanks for the update. I guess unreachable code does not generate a warnnig, in this case.

Comment: Right now, I don't get any working and no error message. The link is display but in button click nothing happened

Comment: I am not sure what you want the end-result to look like. If it's just shortening longer strings, then you can see an example of that on [this official documentation page](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). Scroll down to the example with the text "_Show ellipsis for long strings_". If that is not what you want, then perhaps you can clarify the question?

Comment: I see your comment (it overlapped with mine). You should probably [edit] the question and add this info there.

Comment: @andrewjames Look at this 
https://imgur.com/nPhSKLU